# Solving $(z+1)^5 = z$ ($z\in\mathbb{C}$)

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

I want to find all complex solutions to $$(z+1)^5 = z$$
My hope was to write it in the form $\alpha^k = 1$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then calculate the $k$th root of unity. In this case, since $z\neq 0$ that reduces this to
$$\biggr(\cfrac{z+1}{z^{1/5}}\biggr)^5 = 1$$
I set $z = re^{i\theta}$. With some algebra the best I could do was that
$$(r^{4/5}\exp(4i\theta/5) + r^{-1/5}\exp(-i\theta/5))^5 = 1$$
Now here I'm stuck.

Comment: “Most” quintic equations can not be solved exactly in terms of algebraic expressions, and I suspect this is one of them.

Comment: Wolfram gives solutions in terms of ${}_4F_3$: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7g1W.png, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+z%5E5+%3D+z-1

Comment: substituting $x=z+1$, your equation is $x^5-x+1=0$. There are two similar famous examples $x^5-x-1=0$ which is non solvable and $x^5+x-1=0$ which is solvable. You could look into this to compute the Galois group

Comment: @LPZ Of course $x^5-x+1=0$ fells into the first category, since replacing $x$ by $-x$ yields $x^5-x-1=0$. :)

Comment: @JianingSong Doh! Got mixed up in the signs, thought it became something else... Thanks, so the original is unsolvable by radicals.

Comment: See [Bring radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical)